# Creating a subplot of "combo" plots (hist + boxplot)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, subplot

I have this code:

```
def data_analysis(column_name):
    analysis = ['ultimate', 'surf']
    for i, num in zip(analysis, range(1,len(analysis)+1)):

        df = df_summary[(df_summary['tariff'] ==  i)]
        sns.set(style="ticks")
        x = df[column_name]
        f, (ax_box, ax_hist) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, 
                                            gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": (.2, .85)})
        sns.boxplot(x, ax=ax_box)
        sns.distplot(x, ax=ax_hist, bins = 50)
        ax_box.set(yticks=[])
        table = '\nDescriptive Stats: \n', df[column_name].describe()
        ax_box.text(df[column_name].mean()*0.2,-1,table,size=12)
        sns.despine(ax=ax_hist)
        sns.despine(ax=ax_box, left=True)
```

Which plots the following:

[plots as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko3C3.png)

But what I am looking for is to create a simple subplot 2 by 1 so that it looks as following:

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSc4n.png)

I have used subplots before but here I am struggling to make it work as I am simultaneously working with two curves on each iteration and did not manage to make it work. The num in the outer for loop is meant to fill in the subplot code such that `ax = fig.add_subplot(1,2,num)` --> this does not work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can accomplish what you want using [GridSpec](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec). The following code should produce what you want using simulated data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

# Fake data
np.random.seed(20200319)
left_data = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 1000, size = (161, 1))
right_data = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 1000, size = (339, 1))
left_data = np.random.randn(161, 1) * 191.3 + 367.3
right_data = np.random.randn(339, 1) * 189.1 + 369.5

# Create a figure and two main subplots
f = plt.figure()
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2, figure=f)

# Create subplots for the Left subplot
gs_left = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec = gs[0])
ax_left_box = f.add_subplot(gs_left[0, :])
ax_left_hist = f.add_subplot(gs_left[1, :], sharex = ax_left_box)

# Create subplots for the right subplot
gs_right = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec = gs[1])
ax_right_box = f.add_subplot(gs_right[0, :])
ax_right_hist = f.add_subplot(gs_right[1, :], sharex = ax_right_box)

# Populate with data
ax_left_box.boxplot(left_data, vert = False)
ax_left_hist.hist(left_data, bins = np.arange(0,1001,20), density = True)
ax_right_box.boxplot(right_data, vert = False)
ax_right_hist.hist(right_data, bins = np.arange(0,1001,20), density = True)

# Formatting
ax_left_box.set_xlim((-200, 1200))
ax_left_box.set_xticks(np.arange(-200, 1201, 200))
ax_left_hist.set_ylim((0, 0.004))
ax_left_hist.set_xlabel("call_duration_per_month")

ax_right_box.set_xlim((-200, 1200))
ax_right_box.set_xticks(np.arange(-200, 1201, 200))
ax_right_hist.set_ylim((0, 0.004))
ax_right_hist.set_xlabel("call_duration_per_month")

plt.suptitle("The main title")
```